# SQLite: INSERT only if price is different from last row

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite simple table with 2 columns:

```
timestamp |last_price
1419873093|900.0
1419874283|900.0
1419940915|900.0
1419946324|916.58
1419946981|914.46
1419947981|800.0
```

I'd like to insert new values only if the price is different from last row price (I don't want consecutive prices to be the same). I can get the price from last row using:

```
SELECT last_price FROM BTC_BRL order by rowid desc limit 1;
```

Then I compare it with the new price, but if I could do this directly in the SQL statement, it would be better and faster.

I tried to use CASE WHEN, but without success.

Thanks!

Comment: You mean the 'last_price' was the 'latest price' that was inserted by time? Nothing to do with 'row id' at all. It is helpful to think of 'id's as 'tokens' that the 'database' uses to keep track of 'stuff' internally. We, as users, use them when we have to, but they are 'magic' things that we don't care anything about. This is so wrong but gives you a mental model to think about your data.

Comment: Now, how to quickly identify the last price? Suggestions: 1) Have a table with with the 'last price' in it. Maintain it with 'triggers'. 2) Have an index on the database by time and have  a 'view' that selects the 'one row ordered by time descending'. It will be very quick as it uses the index. I would use (2) as a first attempt.  Do not use the 'id' column

Comment: Ryan I suppose that prices could be duplicate but they cant be like near each other. In that case just use a unique clause when defining the table column and inset with INSERT OR IGNORE.

Comment: @MiguelL, is about 'latest prices' not 'duplicates'. So just the 'latest one by time' is is that is needed to compare against. 'Duplicates by time' is ok. According to my appreciation of the question.

Comment: Ops, Ryan is right. I replied too fast. The "INSERT OR IGNORE" applies to all previous prices, not only the latest price.

Ryan, I'll try the trigger suggestion.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out.  Here is the [SQLFiddle - Latest Price View](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac20b/2).

Comment: Ryan, in fact getting the latest price isn't the problem. The problem is to avoid a INSERT with the latest price. If I could "INSERT OR IGNORE" using only the VIEW it would solve the issue.

Comment: I'm reverting your update, because it's inappropriate. If you found a solution and want to share it, post it as an actual answer in the space provided for doing so. Self-answering is acceptable here, and how to do so is explained in the [help/self-answer].

Comment: No problem Ken. I posted as a answer (I forgor I could answer my own questions). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's the **SOLUTION**:

The solution is with VIEW and TRIGGER:

1) first we create a VIEW with the last row:

```
CREATE VIEW [BTC_BRL-VIEW] AS SELECT timestamp,last_price
FROM [BTC_BRL] order by rowid desc limit 1;
```

2) then we create a TRIGGER using INSTEAD OF:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [BTC_BRL-TRIGGER] INSTEAD OF INSERT 
ON [BTC_BRL-VIEW]

WHEN new.last_price NOT IN (SELECT last_price FROM 
[BTC_BRL-VIEW])

BEGIN INSERT INTO [BTC_BRL] values(new.timestamp,new.last_price);
END;
```

3) finally we can INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO [BTC_BRL-VIEW] values(1419991328,925.47);
```

And that's it! It will only insert if the last price is different from last_price (from VIEW). I hope it helps others too ;)

Answer (score 0):

[SQLFiddle - Insert valid new price](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0aa61/1)

Just change the @price and @when variables and it will insert or not depending on the 'join' conditions. 
It will only insert one row depending on:

- the new value being not equal to the latest one
- the new date must be later than the latest one

I use 'view's to simplify queries when i am debugging them - nothing special about them.

Any questions please post comments.

The code is in the 'fiddle' look for:

```
SET @price = 100,
    @when1 = UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-01-01 11:00:00');

INSERT INTO history_price (price, whenchanged)
SELECT new_price, new_time
FROM  (SELECT
     @price AS new_price, @when1 AS new_time
       ) AS proposed_price 
       JOIN latest_price
          ON proposed_price.new_price != latest_price.price
          AND proposed_price.new_time > latest_price.whenchanged
```

Other stuff you need: latest_price view:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `testmysql`$$

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `latest_price`$$

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`test`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `latest_price` AS 
SELECT
  `history_price`.`price`       AS `price`,
  `history_price`.`whenchanged` AS `whenchanged`,
  FROM_UNIXTIME(`history_price`.`whenchanged`) AS `whendate`
FROM `history_price`
ORDER BY `history_price`.`whenchanged` DESC
LIMIT 1$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The test data you have already

You could also use a correlated query as follows:

SET @price = 900,
    @when1 = UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-12-31 10:00:00');

```
INSERT INTO history_price (price, whenchanged)
SELECT new_price, new_time
FROM  (SELECT
     @price AS new_price, @when1 AS new_time
       ) AS proposed_price  
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM latest_price
          WHERE proposed_price.new_price != latest_price.price
            AND proposed_price.new_time > latest_price.whenchanged)
```